# Xcode 9 Tableview resizing error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, resize

I am really bummed because I just released this app to the App Store, and now that I have updated to Xcode 9, a tableview I had is now having problems. The old tableview, in iOS 10, places the cell around 100 coordinates below the top of the tableview, so I was able to add labels and stuff above the tableview, with the cells starting out below them, but then able to be scrolled under them. But now when I run the app on an ios11 simulator, it gets rid of the tableview header, but when I run it on my own phone, it does not. I have not set any code determining the header of the tableview, and this is my current code:

```
  myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 110, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 140)
```

and is a photo to help visualize it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZQo1.jpg

I need to get the tableview to be equal to the tableview in the iPhone 6s rather than the simulator

Comment: Very confusing how you mention Xcode 9 and iOS 10 and iOS 11, and "my own phone". Are you saying that when you built in Xcode 8 it worked on both iOS 10 and iOS 11, but when you build with Xcode 9 it only works on iOS 10 and not on iOS 11? Either way, you should not *only* use `myTableView.frame = ...` when deciding where the tableView should be. You should use constraints, or let storyboard use autolayout for you. When done by code, you have no idea what different screen sizes will do. My guess is that the new `safeArea`-thing is moving your stuff, but hard to say by this unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that exact line of code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Put this in your ViewController.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 110, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 140)
}
```

It is very poor coding to deal with constant sizes like you do. You should rather create a tableHeader, or constraint a `UIView` above the tableView - where the height of this UIView is based on the size of its content. 
In your code, what happens if the user turns on bigger fonts in Accessibility? The text might grow outside your 100pt view..

If my code doesn't work, try using some of the new safeArea-variables, e.g:

```
myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 110+self.view.safeAreaInsets.top, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 140)
```

Play around with the `safeAreaInsets` until you understand what they do.